# Filtering out records with multiple rownumbers SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to use ROWNUMBER() to filter out records with multiple rownumbers.

E.g.

- Include records with only one row?

or

- Exclude records with more than one rn?

Code so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ID, blah, blah2, 
         ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY blah, blah2) AS rn 
     ORDER BY ID) 
WHERE rn IS ONLY 1;
```

Comment: use `count(*)` instead of `row_number()`

Comment: Is the intention to eliminate records with duplicated ID? You are nearly done. Use ROW_NUMBER and WHERE rn= 1. You need not ORDER BYid.

Comment: Not exactly, I explained the problem terribly... but managed to solve it now!

Answer (score 0):

actually you did it almost correct:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ID, blah, blah2, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY blah, blah2) AS rn
     FROM table_name
     WHERE ... 
    ) 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: This would output all records with rn = 1, but not exclude all the records that have a rn of 1 as well as rn>1.

Comment: Sorry, but in this case i don't get what are you trying to achieve... And what is 'm' in your comment?

Comment: It was explained terribly but solved now so no worries, and do you mean 'rn'? If so then rownumber